# Passing array to a segue

Tags: ios, arrays, segue

I'm trying to pass an array from view A to segue B, here's the code:

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"B"]) {
        BViewController *B = [segue destinationViewController];
        [B setBArray:self.AArray];
}
```

I've declared BArray as property in BViewCOntroller:

```
  @property (retain) NSMutableArray *BArray;
```

and **synthesized** it....

and the error is

```
NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UINavigationController setBArray:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance...
```

where am i wrong? Thank you in advance,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The destinationViewController is returning a UINavigationController, not a BViewController.  Are you segueing to a new UINavigationController? May be a mistake in your storyboard.

Comment: thank you, fine!!! I was segueing a Navigation Controller; so I solved like this:

Comment: UINavigationController *segueNavigation = [segue destinationViewController];
        BViewController *B = (BViewController*)[[segueNavigation viewControllers] objectAtIndex:0];
        [BController setBArray:self.AArray];

Comment: Guys, [segue destinationViewController] returns exactly that view controller to which segue pointing. Not a UINavigationController.