# Pass data to UITableViewController via segue

Tags: iphone, uitableview, segue

I'm trying to pass data from tableViewController to another tableViewController via segue when press a button.

This is my code in the first tableViewController:

```
-(IBAction)openSettings:(id)sender{

 [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"openSettings" sender:sender];
}

- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
 if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"openSettings"]) {

    SettingsTableViewController *settings = (SettingsTableViewController *)[segue      destinationViewController];
    settings.selectedIndex = 0;

 }
}
```

I added the identifier (openSettings) in the destination table in the storyboard.
I'm trying to get the value of variable (selectedIndex) in the destination table that called 
(SettingsTableViewController), but when I run and press the button, it gives me the following Exception:

```
-[UINavigationController setSelectedIndex:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x9b28620
 *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UINavigationController setSelectedIndex:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x9b28620'
```

How can I fix this issue? 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Check this post: I guess its related:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10147500/passing-array-to-a-segue?rq=1